# Slow computer because of bad SSD?

Tags: ssd, hardware-failure, virus, top

my computer normaly is working very fast ( for me), but sometimes start to work very slowly ( it is 3-rd time). I have system on ssd drive. I have read tha it may be bad ssd drive.
I checked:

```
 df
```

the result:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb5      114336932 42097068  66388780  39% /
/dev/sdb1         523248       12    523236   1% /boot/efi
```

and :

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb1
```

the result:

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.11.0-17-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     SandForce Driven SSDs
Device Model:     KINGSTON SV300S37A120G
Serial Number:    50026B723602E7D6
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0026b7 23602e7d6
Firmware Version: 507KC4
User Capacity:    120 034 123 776 bytes [120 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS, ACS-2 T13/2015-D revision 3
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Jun 14 21:38:56 2021 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  48) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0021) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0/3097757
  5 Retired_Block_Count     0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours_and_Msec 0x0032   083   083   000    Old_age   Always       -       15382h+14m+34.020s
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3561
 13 Soft_Read_Error_Rate    0x000a   046   046   000    Old_age   Always       -       247657/3097757
100 Gigabytes_Erased        0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       9497
170 Reserve_Block_Count     0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       3680
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0030   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       845
177 Wear_Range_Delta        0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       4
181 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 IO_Error_Detect_Code_Ct 0x0032   100   100   090    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0000   026   056   000    Old_age   Offline      -       26 (Min/Max 14/56)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   026   056   000    Old_age   Always       -       26 (Min/Max 14/56)
195 ECC_Uncorr_Error_Count  0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/3097757
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
198 Uncorrectable_Sector_Ct 0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/3097757
199 SATA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
201 Unc_Soft_Read_Err_Rate  0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/3097757
204 Soft_ECC_Correct_Rate   0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/3097757
230 Life_Curve_Status       0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
231 SSD_Life_Left           0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       14
233 SandForce_Internal      0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       9893
234 SandForce_Internal      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       9075
241 Lifetime_Writes_GiB     0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       9075
242 Lifetime_Reads_GiB      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       4470

SMART Error Log not supported

SMART Self-test Log not supported

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Should I replace ssd or look for other reasons ?

---------- edit ---------------

Is it a software  ?

```
 top

top - 21:25:20 up  2:51,  1 user,  load average: 0,42, 0,55, 0,48
Tasks: 316 total,   2 running, 314 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  8,9 us,  0,2 sy,  0,0 ni, 90,9 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :  15788,4 total,  10515,8 free,   1962,9 used,   3309,8 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048,0 total,   2048,0 free,      0,0 used.  13214,3 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                                            
   2958 root      20   0 1648352 272488 135356 R  57,2   1,7  40:38.09 Xorg                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   3185 a         20   0 5846996 445648 195956 S  13,2   2,8   8:16.90 gnome-shell                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   7394 a         20   0  752216  57064  43084 S   2,4   0,4   0:03.78 gnome-terminal-                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   9972 a         20   0   36,5g 173208 113976 S   1,0   1,1   0:40.15 brave                                                                                                                                                                                                              
   1084 root      20   0  244004   8944   6976 S   0,2   0,1   0:00.30 accounts-daemon                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  10293 a         20   0   15612   4268   3376 R   0,2   0,0   0:00.06 top                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      1 root      20   0  166916  13432   7928 S   0,0   0,1   0:02.37 systemd                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-events_highpri                                                                                                                                                                                        
      9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq                                                                                                                                                                                                       
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_tasks_rude_                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_tasks_trace                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.05 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     13 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:01.37 rcu_sched                                                                                                                                                                                                          
     14 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.05 migration/0                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     15 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 idle_inject/0                                                                                                                                                                                                      
     16 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0                                                                                                                                                                                                            
     17 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1                                                                                                                                                                                                            
     18 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 idle_inject/1                                                                                                                                                                                                      
     19 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.17 migration/1                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     20 root      20   0       0   
...
```

----- edit 2--------

```
clamscan --remove=yes -i -r ~/
/home/a/.cache/pip/wheels/b6/b9/61/ac0f45350983e50eff5fe94b0278ac04c22b02915249c225eb/Cuckoo-2.0.7-py2-none-any.whl: Win.Virus.Triusor-6887833-0 FOUND
/home/a/.cache/pip/wheels/b6/b9/61/ac0f45350983e50eff5fe94b0278ac04c22b02915249c225eb/Cuckoo-2.0.7-py2-none-any.whl: Removed.

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 8539185
Engine version: 0.103.2
Scanned directories: 23085
Scanned files: 199833
Infected files: 1
Total errors: 1
Data scanned: 15074.42 MB
Data read: 14939.41 MB (ratio 1.01:1)
Time: 1789.710 sec (29 m 49 s)
Start Date: 2021:06:15 22:58:21
End Date:   2021:06:15 23:28:11
```

============== edit ===========

the mouse pointer was moving with steps.
Refreshing the windows was very slow. The cooling was very noisy.    Such signs shows that this is a problem with graphic card and cpu is working heavy.

Comment: It's *tiny*. How full is it? SSDs hate to be running out of nicely trimmed sectors. If it's having to erase every time it writes it will slow to a crawl. SSDs need to have at least 10% free space… though ironically much more at that size, maybe 30GB free at minimum, for smooth operation.

Comment: `/dev/sdb1` is the EFI partition of about 500MB. We need the info for the system partition. In any case, the SMART data shows that the disk is in good shape, so any slow-down must be caused by software.

Comment: @harrymc - not neccessarily so.   I had a similar size SSD, and it just got slow with age, even though it was not particularly full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by wrong graphic card driver. I was updating Ubuntu and smth have changed. I changed the driver and it works well. The ssd drive has error so I plan to change it ( but it was not a bottle neck)